# C# add external scripts in footer from code behind (Sitecore)

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, sitecore

How can I add an external script reference to the footer?
I know how to add it to the header as in the code below but it needs to be on the bottom of the page.

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
   {
      var javascriptRef = new LiteralControl("<script src=\"/js/vendor/jquery.bxslider.min.js\"></script>");
      Page.Header.Controls.Add(javascriptRef);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have in your aspx file next lines of code(add a Literal control just before the end of body tag) :

```
 <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litScript"/>
 </body>
```

From code behind you have :

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPageEditor)
   {
     litScript.Text="<script src=\"/js/vendor/jquery.bxslider.min.js\"></script>";

   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For projects where individual controls/sublayouts control the scripts that they include on the page, I typically use `Page.ClientScript` to manage script inclusions.

`ClientScriptManager` has a number of useful methods for including scripts within a page, and will detect if a script has already been included by comparing the types and script names so that scripts aren't included multiple times (could be nice for handling dependencies, but I prefer to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)).

The three main script registration methods are:

- `RegisterClientScriptBlock`
- `RegisterClientScriptInclude`
- `RegisterStartupScript`

<sub>`RegisterClientScriptBlock` dumps the script at the top of the page</sub>

```
Page.ClientScript
    .RegisterClientScriptBlock(
         GetType(),
         scriptName,
         "<script>alert('do stuff');</script>");
```

<sub>`RegisterClientScriptInclude` dumps `<script src="">` at the top of the page</sub>

```
Page.ClientScript
    .RegisterClientScriptInclude(
         GetType(),
         scriptName,
         "path/to/scriptname.js");
```

<sub>`RegisterStartupScript` dumps the script at the bottom of the page</sub>

```
Page.ClientScript
    .RegisterStartupScript(
         GetType(),
         scriptName,
         "<script>alert('do stuff');</script>");
```

Unfortunately there's no native `RegisterStartupScriptInclude` which would allow for external scripts to be added to the bottom of the page, so I wrote an extension method:

```
public static class ClientScriptManagerExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Registers the startup script with the <see cref="Page"/> object using a type,
    /// a key, and a url
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">
    /// The <see cref="ClientScriptManager"/> with which the script should be registered
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="type">The type of startup script to register</param>
    /// <param name="key">The key of the startup script to register</param>
    /// <param name="url">The url of the startup script include to register</param>
    public static void RegisterStartupScriptInclude(this ClientScriptManager source,
                                                    Type type,
                                                    string key,
                                                    string url)
    {
        if (source == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        var script = string.Format(@"<script src=""{0}""></script>", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(url));
        source.RegisterStartupScript(type, key, script);
    }
}
```

This allows developers to register external scripts to be executed at the close of the `</form>` element, which tends to be close enough to `</body>` for purposes of performance.

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScriptInclude(Page.GetType(), "jquery", "path/to/jquery.js");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScriptInclude(GetType(), "mycontrol", "path/to/mycontrol.js");
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer

Answer (score 2):

The .Net aspx ultimately boils down to the structure of an html page. An html page by definition has a header and a body, no footer.

So if you have this definition in the .aspx

```
<html>
<head runat="server"/>
<body>[Some content]</body>
</html>
```

you can use

```
 Page.Header.Controls.Add(javascriptRef);
```

In order to just inject it in the body, you can use

```
 Page.Controls.Add(javascriptRef);
```

Or you can do what @sitecore climber suggested.